# What is wrong with my intent.putExtras (Cannot resolve string)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need to get the address and pass it to google map . I have pass all the data to DisplayItem Activity. Now, from Displayitem activity I just want to pass the address to MapActivity.

This is the activity which i have successful display all the data using . After that I created a button so user can go to the mapActivity to see the location.

```
private Bundle extras;

private TextView mallAddress;
private TextView tvMallName;
private TextView state, url, phone_number, mail,wb,pn, town;

ImageView map_Locations;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displayitem);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tvMallName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mallname);
    state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.states);
    mallAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mall_Address);

    map_Locations= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_location);



    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String malladress = extras.getString(EXTRA_ADDRESS,"");
    String mallName = extras.getString(EXTRA_NAME, "");
    String mallstate = extras.getString(EXTRA_STATE,"");


    mallAddress.setText(malladress);
    tvMallName.setText(mallName);
    state.setText(mallstate);

}
```

This is the button that I've created (I have problem with my string "address") Am I doing it wrong?It says (Cannot resolve string,string) at intent.putExtras()

```
public void map(View view){
    map_Locations= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_location);
    map_Locations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String address = mallAddress.getText().toString();
            Intent intent= new Intent(Displayitem.this, MapsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtras(MapsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}
```

On the MapActivity I retrieve the data

```
 private void getAddress(GoogleMap googleMap)  {

   try {
       mMap = googleMap;
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       extras = intent.getExtras();

       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);


       address = extras.getString(this.EXTRA_ADDRESS);

       location = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
       if (location.size() > 0) {
           lati =location.get(0).getLatitude();
           lon =location.get(0).getLongitude();
           MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                   .title(name)
                   .position (new LatLng(lati, lon));
           mMap.addMarker(options);
       }

   }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();

   }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    getAddress(googleMap);
    setUpMap();

}
```

ps. Im newbie

Answer (score 3):

Not

```
intent.putExtras(...);
```

it's  just `intent.putExtra(...)`

```
intent.putExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
```

Check the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Im so laughing out loud now. HAHAHAHHAA. I was so DUMB. OMG O_O.. haha ty for waking me up

Comment: @Critako Take some rest and get some  refreshment.